# How to create Live Agent Chat Invitation with REST API

Tags: rest-api, liveagent

We need some guidance with the Live Agent REST API Chat Invitation. We scoured the REST API documentation but found nothing to guide us with implementing the chat invitation (Only info for Deployment API). There is clearly some button properties that are used for the chat invitation listed in V.39 of the Live Agent REST developer guide https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_data_types.htm

But we would like some code samples or guidance on how to use these to create a automated invitation. Can someone provide us code samples or written outline of the approach to use REST API to create a chat invitation?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is late. I have posted a working example of Live Agent REST API written in Java. Please refer to this Salesforce Stack Exchange Question [Unable to send chat message in live agent via REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179207/unable-to-send-chat-message-in-live-agent-via-rest-api/185833#185833).

*Note:- Though this is a link only answer, I don't want to duplicate the answer in two places in SFSE.*